# javascript, can this code (nested IF statement) be shorter?

Tags: javascript

I think below code can be simpleer somehow. Can this code be optimized?

```
let name = app.short_name;
  if (name === undefined) {
    name = app.name;
    if (name === undefined) {
      name = 'Untitled';
    }
  }
```

Comment: yes, `name` could be `n` :p `let name = app.short_name || app.name || 'Untitled';`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a default chain with [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()) in a [short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation).

```
let name = app.short_name || app.name || 'Untitled';
```

But I suggest to use a variable name different of `name`, because it is usually a property of [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name)

Answer (score 9):

Use [**`Logical OR`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()) (`||`) operator

```
let name = app.short_name || app.name || 'Untitled';
```

Answer (score 4):

Javascript will assign what it considers `true`. If you concat with `||` (`OR`) then each value is checked for true until a true value is found and is assigned.

There are a number of values that become `false` for example:

- `undefined`
- `0`
- `null`
- `''` (empty String)
- `NaN`

This is why you could write

```
let name = app.short_name || app.name || 'Untitled';
```

because if `app.short_name` has a value it will be `true` rather than `false` and it is assigned. But if it is `undefined` it will be considered `false` and `app.name` will be checked if it is `true`. If it is `undefined` it will be again considered `false` and so finally `'Untitled'` is considered and deemed `true` and assigned to `name`. Might want to look at this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).

Comment: appreciate you for the additional infomation. helped me to learn :)